# nginx-php doesn't work with own build nginx

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I compiled NGINX with this configure command:

```
./configure --with-http_ssl_module --add-module=../nginx-rtmp-module-master
```

Then I did make install to install it, it has been successfully added but I can't execute PHP file, it gives to me an error when i try to open page :( (I have installed php-fpm)

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        #server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        root html;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            #fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}

rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                }
        }
}
```

And here is the error log output:

```
2014/09/10 15:52:16 [notice] 22803#0: signal process started
2014/09/10 15:52:39 [notice] 22808#0: signal process started
2014/09/10 15:57:21 [notice] 22819#0: signal process started
2014/09/10 16:02:15 [error] 22891#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while c$
2014/09/10 16:03:36 [crit] 22947#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (13$
2014/09/10 16:05:41 [crit] 23002#0: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (13$
2014/09/10 16:06:26 [crit] 23057#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (13$
2014/09/10 16:06:26 [crit] 23057#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (13$
2014/09/10 16:06:27 [crit] 23057#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (13$
```

It's looks like to not have permission, but how can I give right permission to nginx ?

Answer (score 0):

Imfamous error with listen directive, it must be equal for nginx and php-fpm.
If you use socket in nginx.conf, then you must use socket in the php-fpm pool conf (e.g. /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf for debian)

nginx.conf (you set it already):

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

php-fpm www.conf:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

If these settings will not help, try set listen.* to nginx's user (e.g. www-data for debian)

php-fpm www.conf:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

Comment: Hello I have just found an other way because what you suggest did not work.
I set:
fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;

then in www.conf i set listen:
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

and it's now working perfectly

Comment: You asked about sockets, you got right answer. You always can say thanks ;) Sockets are default nix way (and faster), but sometimes need more configuration. IP:port notation is OK for starters, glad that you solved problem.